# MVC ActionLink not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My goal is have the link appear as mydomain.com/viewPhone/1

Currently, the link is appearing as Home/phoneCatalog  , and without displaying my ID

**ROUTING**

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "phoneCatalog",
        url: "viewPhone/{phoneID}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "phoneCatalog",}
    );
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult phoneCatalog(int phoneID)
{
//CODE HERE
}
```

**MVC VIEW**

```
<span class="floatL w100">@Html.ActionLink(title, "phoneCatalog", "Home", new { phoneID = orderItem.phoneID }, null)


              </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Html.RouteLink` instead. You probably still have the fall-back `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route defined.

```
@Html.RouteLink(title, "phoneCatalog", new { phoneID = orderItem.phoneID })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use attribute routing. It gives you more flexibility if you like different names for your actions rather than default values.

It is easy to use.

Check out: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

```
[Route("viewPhone/{phoneID:int}")]
public ActionResult phoneCatalog(int phoneID)
{
//CODE HERE
}
```

Try this.